# Copy contents of unique_ptr to unknown derived class

Tags: c++

I have an abstract base class, with several concrete derived classes; none of these classes manage any resources.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

// this is a pure abstract class that contains no resources
class Base {
public:
    Base() {};
    virtual int doSomething() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived()  {};

    // this mutates the derived class
    int doSomething() override { return 0; };
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
    Derived2() {};

    // this mutates the derived class
    int doSomething() override { return 0; };
};
```

and I have a function that returns a random derived instance (Derived1, Derived2, Derived3, depending upon a random number throw).

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> randomDerivedInstance() {
    // pick a random number here and return Derived1 or Derived2 etc.
    // for the purpose of this problem, I'm just returning a fixed derived class
    return std::make_unique<Derived>();
}
```

and I have a struct that I want to store this derived instance in

```
struct DataStruct {

    // this can contain Derived1 or Derived2
    std::unique_ptr<Base> base;

    // other things in struct omitted for clarity

    // obviously this won't work
    DataStruct(std::unique_ptr<Base> base) : base(base) {};
};
```

I return a unique pointer from my random function, and want to save a copy into the struct, and then call `doSomething` on it that performs several mutating operations on the class internals, and I don't want them to affect the copy stored in the list.

If I knew the type of the derived instance, I would use a copy constructor to create a new instance and add it to the vector, but in this situation I don't know the specific type of the instance I'm trying to add, so I don't know which specific constructor to use.

```
int main() {
    // I want to create a vector of random instances
    std::vector<DataStruct> list;

    // I create a random instance
    auto myDerived = randomDerivedInstance();

    // and I want to push a copy of myDerived before I do something with it
    // obviously this doesn't work because its a unique_ptr
    // what can I do here?
    list.push_back(DataStruct(myDerived));

    // do something that mutates myDerived
    myDerived->doSomething();

    // I don't want my mutations to myDerived to affect the list copy


}
```

The code above doesn't compile for obvious reasons since I'm trying to assign a `unique_ptr` in the `DataStruct` constructor.

What changes do I need to make to this architecture and code in order to get this to work as intended? i.e. add a value-copy of random derived instance to a struct, so that I can mutate the original instance (or vice-versa, add original, and mutate copy).

Thanks for all help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class `Base` add a virtual member function `clone`:

```
virtual auto clone() const
    -> std::unique_ptr<Base>
    = 0;
```

In each derived class `Derived` override that to provide a derived class specific clone:

```
auto clone() const
    -> std::unique_ptr<Base>
    override
{ return std::unique_ptr<Base>( new Derived{ *this } ); }
```

It's possible to do this in a more advanced way where if you know the most derived class at compile you can get a clone statically of that type, but it doesn't appear that you need that.

Disclaimer: off-the-cuff code, not reviewed by compiler.

---

At one time, long ago, a `clone` function was called a virtual constructor, and that term is used in [the FAQ item about this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions#virtual-ctors). I think it was introduced by Coplien. The current FAQ text doesn't say.

---

Also worth noting: in C++11 and later the generation of `clone` function implementations can be partially automated by `Derived` inheriting from an implementation that in turn inherits from `Base`, with forwarding of constructor arguments.

C++03 didn't support forwarding so then one had to use schemes such as code-generating macro (evil but in practice the only real solution back then), implementation inheritance via dominance in a virtual inheritance hierarchy (extremely complex and ugly), or to do the same as we now can do in C++11 and later, but with a Do-It-Yourself argument forwarding scheme (somewhat arbitrary limited).

For an overview of these old C++03 techniques see my 2010 blog article “[3 ways to mix in a generic cloning implementation](https://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/06/12/cppx-3-ways-to-mix-in-a-generic-cloning-implementation/)”.

Comment: `virtual auto clone() const -> std::unique_ptr<Base> = 0`?  What's wrong with `virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const = 0`?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: In my code it would needlessly introduce the old C style syntax for no gain. What do you think the advantage of that old syntax (in your opinion) is?

Comment: It seems needlessly verbose.  You're telling the compiler to figure out what the return type should be, but then going off and telling it what that type is, which sorta defeats the purpose.

Comment: No, that's not what `auto` means in this context. I agree that `auto` is a very unfortunate choice of keyword here. And it got worse with C++14 where the meaning of that keyword, introducing function with trailing return type, or standing in for the return type in a C style declaration, depends on what follows after the function head. Current editors fail to track that with syntax highlighting. But the poor committee didn't have much to choose from, to avoid breaking code.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, and very well explained and documented! Kudos!

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I know that there's a difference between using `auto` with a _trailing return type_ and when it is used to deduce the type from a return statement, but when I read the code that's how I read it.